# Installing a Windows Service under a User account

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm developing an application that requires me to install a Windows Service as a user (so far, I was registering successfully it as `LocalSystem`, but the requirements had changed).

I'm aware that, if I set `ServiceAccount` as `User`, it would prompt me with the credentials. That's ok for me. But when I hit ok, it gives me an error saying username or password are wrong, even after I triple-check it.

I can only "bypass" it by changing the Log On property AFTER I've installed the Windows Service, which is not ideal. Am I wrong about something? Here's the snippet of code I'm trying to use.

```
process = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
process.Account = ServiceAccount.User; //.LocalSystem works fine.
service = new ServiceInstaller();
service.ServiceName = "myService";
service.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
Installers.Add(process);
Installers.Add(service);
```

Comment: is it a domain user and you didnt provide the domain eg domain\user

Comment: It is a simple Windows user, with administrative privileges. I just provided username and password. I didn't know I should put the domain aswell. I'll give it a try.

Comment: chances are it will be looking locally for the account ergo it will say No